# Emit multiple actions within catchError - Redux Observable

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I have my auth function using rxjs epics:

```
export const authWithEmailPasswordEpic = action$ =>
action$.pipe(
    filter(authUser.match),
    switchMap(({payload}) =>
        defer(() =>
            from(firebaseEmailPasswordAuth(payload)).pipe(
                mergeMap(() => of(clearAlertState(), stopLoading())),
                catchError(err =>
                    of(clearState(), createAlert({
                        status: err.code,
                        alertType: RED_ALERT,
                        alertTitle: err.message
                    })),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

If the users credentials are incorrect, I am dispatching an alert, but then I also want to remove the alert after 5 seconds or so. Therefore, I believe I'd need to emit two actions to achieve this, with the second one being:

`of(toggleAlert()).pipe(delay(5000)))`

How would I achieve this or is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `delay(5000)` after `catchError`, then `mergeWith` the `of(toggleAlert())`, like the following:

```js
export const authWithEmailPasswordEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(authUser.match),
    switchMap(({ payload }) =>
      defer(() =>
        from(firebaseEmailPasswordAuth(payload)).pipe(
          mergeMap(() => of(clearAlertState(), stopLoading())),
          catchError(err =>
            of(
              clearState(),
              createAlert({
                status: err.code,
                alertType: RED_ALERT,
                alertTitle: err.message
              })
            )
          ),
          mergeWith(of(toggleAlert()).pipe(delay(5000)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. This will delay any action (including `clearState` and `createAlert`) by 5000ms, and then replace all of them for `toggleAlert` before they get emitted.

Comment: Yes, you alright, my bad. Thanks for your comment. Btw I updated my answer. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track... For a simpler version I would use `concat`, I think it reads better:

```js
export const authWithEmailPasswordEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(authUser.match),
    switchMap(({ payload }) =>
      from(firebaseEmailPasswordAuth(payload)).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => of(clearAlertState(), stopLoading())),
        catchError((err) =>
          concat(
            [
              clearState(),
              createAlert({
                status: err.code,
                alertType: RED_ALERT,
                alertTitle: err.message,
              }),
            ],
            timer(5000).pipe(
              mapTo(toggleAlert())
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

With this pattern you can then make it fancier. Imagine you want to dispatch `toggleAlert` except if the user has made `Action.CloseAlert`. Then you can swap that timer.pipe for:

```js
timer(5000).pipe(
  mapTo(toggleAlert()),
  takeUntil(action$.pipe(
    filter((action) => action.type === Action.CloseAlert)
  ))
);
```

Another note - I don't think that `defer()` is needed here. switchMap immediately subscribes to the result fo the function, so it shouldn't really matter. Add it back if you need it